# When a face collapses into a swirling black hole on a video conference call like this is it due to some advanced AI-based error-correction gone wrong?

Tags: video-processing, deep-learning, video-compression, artificial-intelligence

Within this newscast video<sup>1</sup> a video conference call is shown. Between `02:23` and `02:37` the face of the interviewee appears to get sucked into a black hole; it starts swirling, there seems to be what looks like the video echo effect one would get pointing a camera at a monitor with the video feed with a delay.

But in this case I'm guessing it's some kind of advanced AI-based error-correction that's trying to fill in the face based on previous data, but failing miserably.

Between 02:31 and 02:32 you can see eyes blinking in a location that's drifted substantially to the left of where the interviewee's head should be.

There's a constant counter-clockwise rotation in the face area, and a chart-recorder like left-to-right motion where the interviewee's shirt tie would be.

**Question:** When someone's face collapses into a swirling black hole on a video conference call like this, is it due to some advanced AI-based error-correction gone wrong?

---

<sup>1</sup>[video cued at `02:23`](https://youtu.be/XzxMnF4gNIs?t=143) But *turn off your volume first* this is not meant to promote the news video or its content/position, but to focus only on the video effect.

A high quality GIF would probably be better but I don't know how to generate one with sufficient quality and length that fits the 2 MiB Stack Exchange limit and yet reproduces the effects accurately.

[image: screenshot of a news video of a video conference where the face of the interviewee starts swirling due to some error-correction algorithm gone wrong https://youtu.be/XzxMnF4gNIs?t=151]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like what pretty "classical" video compression does when facing severe data loss – notice the very MPEG-typical square blocks, and how some of the probably more changing blocks are getting "updates" in your still? That's because, although the last reference frame was lost, the decoder tries its best to reconstruct an image based on the differences it receives.

In the video, there's an upwards-right motion – and that's probably just classical motion prediction doing exactly the same: after experiencing an erasure of a data packet, just continue the last known movement. Since different parts of a human face move in different directions, I can see how this can cause a "curl-y" effect. The fact that it's limited to the facial region probably just means that the motion predicted blocks were declared to be limited to that area – which also makes morphological sense.

So, no, nothing specifically deep-learning going on here, but probably one of the more modern variants of MPEG-4 paired with heavy packet loss and probably a link that does its very best to avoid these, while being severely limited by the maximum allowable latency (can't have 20 seconds worth of interleaving if the video needs to show someone answering a question).

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer; I didn't know that motion prediction was part of MPEG-4 or related compression schemes and would like to read more about that. Can you add at least one source to support your answer? *Thanks!*

Comment: I'd start just by doing a web search on MPEG.  Or "mpeg book", which will get you _lots_ of reading material.  MPEG has been around for a good long time, it's complicated, and there's a lot of interest in it -- so there's a proportionally high amount of material out there.

Comment: @TimWescott I see, prediction seems *central* to MPEG-4 and so is obvious to everyone except me (until now at least) :-) https://sciendo.com/article/10.2478/v10187-011-0010-6